# creating a graph of dictionary data?

Tags: python, dictionary, graph

I'm really new to python and just trying to get some basic practice in.  I started creating basic functions today and wanted to do a similar project to [this project here.](https://github.com/wblakecannon/DataCamp/blob/master/03-python-data-science-toolbox-(part-1)/2-default-arguments-variable-length-arguments-and-scope/bringing-it-all-together-(1).py)

I wanted to use a different dataset ([a superbowl data set](https://github.com/veeralakrishna/DataCamp-Portfolio-Project-Solutions--Python/blob/master/TV%2C%20Halftime%20Shows%2C%20and%20the%20Big%20Game/datasets/super_bowls.csv)) to do the same code as the project I linked above.  I wanted to use the same code to count the number of times a team won the superbowl. I got the code to work just fine, but now I'm curious about graphing this data. I use matplotlib.pyplot for most of my graphs, but this doesn't work since I'm using a dictionary of data.  How can I graph this data, perhaps with teams on one axis and their wins on the other?  The code is below:

```
 # Import pandas
import pandas as pd

# Import Twitter data as DataFrame: df
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/veeralakrishna/DataCamp-Portfolio-Project-Solutions--Python/master/TV%2C%20Halftime%20Shows%2C%20and%20the%20Big%20Game/datasets/super_bowls.csv")

# Define count_entries()
def count_winners(df, col_name='team_winner'):
    """Return a dictionary with counts of
    wins as value for each team."""

    # Initialize an empty dictionary: cols_count
    wins_count = {}

    # Extract column from DataFrame: col
    col = df[col_name]

    # Iterate over the column in DataFrame
    for entry in col:

       # If entry is in wins_count, add 1
        if entry in wins_count.keys():
           wins_count[entry] += 1

       # Else add the entry to wins_count, set the value to 1
         else:
           wins_count[entry] = 1

# Return the cols_count dictionary
return wins_count
```

This returns the dictionary that I would like to graph:

```
{'Philadelphia Eagles': 1, 'New England Patriots': 5, 'Denver Broncos': 3, 'Seattle Seahawks': 1, 'Baltimore Ravens': 2, 'New York Giants': 4, 'Green Bay Packers': 4, 'New Orleans Saints': 1, 'Pittsburgh Steelers': 6, 'Indianapolis Colts': 1, 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers': 1, 'St. Louis Rams': 1, 'Dallas Cowboys': 5, 'San Francisco 49ers': 5, 'Washington Redskins': 3, 'Chicago Bears': 1, 'Los Angeles Raiders': 1, 'Oakland Raiders': 2, 'Miami Dolphins': 2, 'Baltimore Colts': 1, 'Kansas City Chiefs': 1, 'New York Jets': 1}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you can't plot a dictionary, using .keys() and .values().  Here's an example showing a horizontal barchart (I chose this orientation so the team names are readable on the Y-axis).  It's based on a simple [horizontal barchart example](https://pythonspot.com/matplotlib-bar-chart/) on Pythonspot.com.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_wins(data):
    teams = data.keys()
    wins = data.values()
    y_pos = np.arange(len(teams))

    plt.barh(y_pos, wins, align='center', alpha=0.5)
    plt.yticks(y_pos, teams)
    plt.xlabel('Wins')
    plt.title('Superbowl Wins by Team')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

plot_wins({ 'Philadelphia Eagles': 1, 'New England Patriots': 5, ..etc..})
```

[image: Horizontal barchart]

Comment: Thank you! this is a really good visualization of what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Like you've mentioned using matplotlib is the best approach for this problem.

Dict contains key, values so what you simply need is a way to iterate through all the keys and use that as a x-values and the dict values as y-values. Python has a lot of built in moduels that can help with this.

`zip` - Zips the element into [tuples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm) such that each key, value becomes e.g. ('New England Patriots', 5)

```py
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

d = {'Philadelphia Eagles': 1, 'New England Patriots': 5, 'Denver Broncos': 3, 'Seattle Seahawks': 1, 'Baltimore Ravens': 2, 'New York Giants': 4, 'Green Bay Packers': 4, 'New Orleans Saints': 1, 'Pittsburgh Steelers': 6, 'Indianapolis Colts': 1, 'Tampa Bay Buccaneers': 1, 'St. Louis Rams': 1, 'Dallas Cowboys': 5, 'San Francisco 49ers': 5, 'Washington Redskins': 3, 'Chicago Bears': 1, 'Los Angeles Raiders': 1, 'Oakland Raiders': 2, 'Miami Dolphins': 2, 'Baltimore Colts': 1, 'Kansas City Chiefs': 1, 'New York Jets': 1}


lists = sorted(d.items()) # sorted by key, return a list of tuples
#You can sort by values using the following, so the graph would look with increaseing gradient
# lists = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
x, y = zip(*lists) # unpack a list of pairs into two tuples
plt.xlabel('Teams')
plt.ylabel('Wins')
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xticks(x,rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

This is the graph the above code produces. You may want to shorten the values for the keys so that it looks better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this is what I was looking for!